# how to avoid logging to /var/log/syslog for a given application?

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I have an application which successfully logs (via local0) to its own files, the problem is that it keeps logging to `/var/log/syslog`, which is what I want to avoid.

```
rsyslog version: rsyslogd  8.1901.0 (aka 2019.01)
```

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` I have tried(one line at time):

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;local0.none      -/var/log/syslog
*.*;local0.none;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
*.*;auth,authpriv,local0.none       -/var/log/syslog
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;local0.!*        -/var/log/syslog
```

but `/var/log/syslog` keeps logging `local0` entries.

After every change that I've tried I restart rsyslog with `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you can discard messages by configs like:

`local0.*    ~`

you must have to add above config after action which writes log into application log file and before default actions which write into `/var/log/syslog`

you can add more condition to discard more specific message if you want!

[discard syntax](https://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/)

Comment: thanks for answer, sadly it has'nt work. I have `local0.* /path/mylog` first, then `local0.* ~` then default line to `syslog` but behaviour is the same, logs of my app go to mylog and syslog